# HAProxy Layer 4 Timeout Error

Tags: haproxy

I was trying to checkout our application code from svn server to Amazon EC2 instance. Our SVN Server is behind the HAproxy Loadbalancer. Unfortunately the checkout process didn't success and I checked the haproxy,I found the error as Layer 4 timeout. Does the error have anything to do with Health Check issue?

Thanks 
Bishal

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this means HAProxy can not connect to your SVN server on its designated port (usually port 3690).

Have you got a route from the HAProxy machine, to the SVN server? (i.e. can you ping it)? If so, can you connect to the port via telnet or netcat (nc).

```
telnet <SVN_IP> <SVN_PORT>
```

Obviously if HAProxy can not talk to the SVN server, then it can not forward on the TCP stream.

Comment: Yeah, I can ping the SVN. And also the strange thing is I can checkout from our dedicated server. But as soon as I try to checkout from EC2, svn server stops.